# Remove last 'n' invalid characters from a string

Tags: sql-server

‌ I have a table with names that may or maynot have invalid characters at the end of the string. How can I remove them? V‌alid Characters are ‌'[a-zA-Z0-9.)]

```
C‌reate table dbo.temp(name varchar(200) null)
i‌nsert into dbo.temp values('Test name1')‌
i‌nsert into dbo.temp values('Test name2#')‌
i‌nsert into dbo.temp values('Test name3 %#%^&^&&&')‌‌‌
i‌nsert into dbo.temp values('------Test Name -----------')
```

I‌ tried this

```
‌SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(Name),1) NOT LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9.)]' THEN SUBSTRING(Name,1,LEN(Name)-1) 
           ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(Name))‌ END as Tname FROM dbo.temp
```

B‌ut this only deletes the last character.

And the last row should return: `------Test Name`

Any suggestions.

Thanks
MR

Comment: From poking around a bit, I might say that you would need a user defined function for this.

Comment: You should probably include space as well? Also, are you wanting to remove all instances of the invalid characters or only at the "end"? If at the end, how do you define the end? Or are you saying end because in your data that is currently the only location of invalid data. And only ) not also (

Comment: I am looking at end only because that's where garbage data is. I had forgotten about space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that works for your test data and should scale to the format you listed in your OP

```
declare @temp table(name nvarchar(500) null)

insert into @temp (name) 
values 
('Test Name')
,('Test Name2#')
,('Test Name @%$%#_')



select
     CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(name),1) NOT LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9.)]' THEN left(name,len(name) - PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9.)]%',reverse(name)) +1)
        ELSE name
     end
from @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove all occurrences of these invalid characters you could use an inline table valued function. This is an adaptation of my function that finds alphanumeric characters.

```
create function RemoveInvalidCharacters
(
    @SearchVal varchar(8000)
) returns table as return
    with MyValues as
    (
        select substring(@SearchVal, N, 1) as value
            , t.N
        from cteTally t 
        where N <= len(@SearchVal)
            and substring(@SearchVal, N, 1) like '[ a-zA-Z0-9.)]'
    )

    select distinct NumValue = REPLACE(STUFF((select value + ''
                from MyValues mv2
                order by mv2.N
                for xml path('')), 1, 0, ''), '&#x20;', ' ') --the replace here is because we need to change the space back to character data
    from MyValues mv
```

The cteTally is just a standard numbers or tally table. I keep one as a view in my system that looks like this.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the same notation, you can purge your table using the following query:

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.temp
    SET    Name = SUBSTRING(Name,1,LEN(Name)-1) 
    WHERE  Name LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9.)]'

    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK
END
```

On every wrong ending, it will remove one character and loop until no row is updated.

EDIT : For those that think it doesn't work, here is a rapid test to play:

```
create table tblTmpTest ( Name varchar(100) )

insert into tblTmpTest
values ('aaa%¨.^'''),
('aaa%¨^'''),
('aaa'),
('aaa%');

select *
from    tblTmpTest;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblTmpTest
    SET    Name = SUBSTRING(Name,1,LEN(Name)-1) 
    WHERE  Name LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9.)]'

    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK
END


select *
from    tblTmpTest;

drop table tblTmpTest;
```

Comment: There is no need for loops here.

Comment: Looking at this further what is the point of the loop anyway?

Comment: Loop here is simplier than a patindex(). Even if it isn't that good in term of performance, it could suit the needs of a light purge used once upon a while.

Comment: But your loop is only going to look at the same character over and over. This is more like pseudocode than a complete answer.

Comment: The point of the loop is using the same logic the writer already used in his/her post but reiterating it. It keep a pseudocode approach for understanding purpose since performance is probably not needed here. (Well it's an assumption here.)

Comment: There is no loop in the original question. And the loop you have here doesn't do anything different on each iteration. It is the same update each pass. As posted this is not just poor from a performance perspective, it simply doesn't work.

Comment: I was talking about removing a character one at a times which is already his/her problem. If you use this request without transaction it works, isn't it?

Comment: Heck, just tried. It works even with transaction. Just try it before telling it doesn't work!

Comment: More it will loop BUT only on the required row (WHERE clause). In terms of performance it won't be that bad than looping over all the table.